# Receive GPS data from android into cakephp - support for gps locations in cakePHP

Tags: android, cakephp, geolocation, gps

I want send my location GPS data from my android phone to a cakePHP website. I navigated my sql and I found the `POINT` type that can be used to store location information. But I don't know how to insert those information using cakePHP style code. I want to be able to get locations near me later in the future. So my questions are:

1 - does cakePHP has any support for storing GPS data and ready functions to get nearby locations given longitude and latitude object.

2 - If not, how to insert the received longitude and latitude into my model in cakePHP and what is the best data type for that as I will query nearby locations after this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution as follow:

To insert data into model in cakePHP given a constructed array we use this :

```
$db = $this->Service->getDataSource();  
$serv = array(
                'name'=>$data['name'],
                'loc_point' => $db->expression('POINT('.$dataJson['long'].','.$dataJson['lat'].')')
            );
$this->Service->save($serv));
```

This line was my problem in cakePHP:
**`'loc_point' => $db->expression('POINT('.$data['lng'].','.$data['lat'].')')`**

After solving the insertion problem I found a tutorial from google getting the nearby location. It uses lng and lat as decimal values, I changed my code to follow it. Link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql)

Answer (score 0):

To store a coordinate as pair of (latitude, longitude) you can store it either as

```
float latitude,
float longitude
```

or as

```
double latitdue,
double longitude
```

(This has no advantage to float, on disk, but in code is more compatible)

Or you even can store it as integer

```
   int latitude = (int) round(latDegrees * 1E7);
   int longitude = (int) round(lonDegrees * 1E7);
```

So you can also store it to any Point structre which has (x,y)
Use x for longitude, and y for latitude.